# change telerik rad scheduler completely to arabic?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

I am a new user Of Telerik ASP.NET Ajax.
After creating a simple RadScheduler I used the Culture Property to change the scheduler to Arabic:

```
Culture="ar-LB"
```

The result :
[image: can i make all the scheduler displayed in arabic]

**Is there any way to change the scheduler completely to arabic with month and change also the advance edit form Start time, End time , Description , Subject to arabic ?**

Comment: Change you windows or browser culture to arabic too.
If the text is still not translated i guess its a traduction issue. Some 'minor' traduction can be missing in telerik. you can do your own ressource file for traduction and Give it to telerik they will rewards you with some telerik point. That are cool discount for your next by on telerik.

Comment: @PierreLebon thank you  i create a Arabic copy of the RadScheduler.Main.resx file and that's work  correctly with me i still have some problem with translating the resource that i added to the scheduler like users and occasions

Comment: if those text are in label you can easly localise them. If they are not just put them into label or the right control.. and btw merry xmas